# ASP.NET MVC add .html in last url parament

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add html in parameters
 
Example : 
 
www.mystorenowopen.com/store.html/12/computer-it

i wrote

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "store",
  "store.html/{cid}/{title}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "store" }
);
```

Its working fine but I want to 
 
www.mystorenowopen.com/store/12/computer-it.html

how to do it

Pls help me

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Comment: Yep, and it's better to have StoreController with action "Index" instead of HomeController with action "store" (and it's better to capitalize the name of your method, because it is public).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
routes.MapRoute( "store", "store/{cid}/{title}.html", new { controller = "Home", action = "store" } );
```